# Why are lines in JS executing upside down

Tags: javascript

I am super confused why Line 2 is executing before Line 1.

I have a function base64 to convert uploaded files into base64. Then I am calling the function base64, and then trying to put the base 64 into a variable. However, the flow is going upside down and not working. Why is the line 2 executing before line 1

```
  function base64(file, callback) {
    var coolFile = {};

    function readerOnload(e) {
      var base64 = btoa(e.target.result);
      coolFile.base64 = base64;
      callback(coolFile);
    }

    ;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = readerOnload;
    var file = file[0].files[0];
    coolFile.filetype = file.type;
    coolFile.size = file.size;
    coolFile.filename = file.name;
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  }

        var fileToSend;

        base64($('input[type="file"]'), function (filedata) {
          var convertedFile = filedata.base64;
          console.log('\n file SB1 \t' + convertedFile);
          fileToSend = convertedFile;
          console.log ('Line 1 \t' + fileToSend);
        });

        console.log('\n Line 2 \t' + fileToSend);
```

Comment: "Line 2" is executed synchronously whereas "Line 1" is executed asynchronously and async code is executed _after_ synchronous code has executed.

Comment: Which line is executing before which line?

Comment: The lines are printed in the console.log.. It is at the end

Comment: @Yousaf How can I make it flow top down?

Comment: It is already top down. Callback function passed to function `base64` is invoked at some later time, _after_ the `base64` function has already executed and "Line 2" has also executed.

Comment: If you need to do stuff after the async operation has finished - then do it inside the callback function, that’s what those are for. If you don’t want that, then you need to go look into stuff like `await` and promises, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fixed version of your code

Your original code was incomplete and had the async issue mentioned in the comments

```js
function base64(file, callback) {
  var coolFile = {};

  function readerOnload(e) { console.log(e.target.result)
    var base64 = btoa(e.target.result);
    coolFile.base64 = base64;
    callback(coolFile);
  }

  ;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = readerOnload;
  var file = file[0].files[0];
  coolFile.filetype = file.type;
  coolFile.size = file.size;
  coolFile.filename = file.name;
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}

$('input[type="file"]').on("change", function() {
  base64([this],
    function(filedata) {
      var convertedFile = filedata.base64; // file to send
      console.log('\n file SB1 \t' + convertedFile);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Your 'Line 1' statement is part of a callback passed to `base64` function. Inside that function you put that callback into another function `readerOnload()`, which is called after FileReader `load` event fires (`reader.onload = readerOnload;`).

Your file needs some time to get loaded into FileReader, and this process is asynchronous, so the Task Queue moves to 'Line 2' before that happens.

To understand better what's happening here check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ